# How to make the nested for loop execute faster in python?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, optimization

Here is my script:

```
for a in range(-100, 101):
    for b in range(-100, 101):
        for c in range(-100, 101):
            for d in range(-100, 101):
                if abs(2**a*3**b*5**c*7**d-0.3048) <= 10**(-6):
                    print('a=',a, ', b=', b, ', c=', c,', d=', d,', the number=', 2**a*3**b*5**c*7**d, ', error=', abs(2**a*3**b*5**c*7**d-.3048))
```

It took 27 mins and 15 seconds to execute the above script in python. I know that it goes through 201^4 expression evaluations, but I need to run these kinds of calculations faster (because I want to try `range(-200,201)` and so on).

I'm wondering if it is possible to make the above code execute faster. I think using `numpy` arrays would help, but not sure how to apply this, and whether it is actually effective.

Comment: Each loop run 200 times, and you have four levels of nesting, for a total of 200^4 (1.6 billion) iterations.  If you do anything one-point-six billion times, it's gonna be slow...

Comment: You can look into itertools.product. It does exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Not sure how many results you get but `print()` is very slow.

Comment: @MelonPie that won't grant any speed-ups for the O.P., though.

Comment: @JonSG I got 24 results.

Comment: What about other programming languages? In general is it possible to do such massive calculations quicker?

Comment: How fast would be fast enough?

Comment: What is the value you're looking to calculate?  Maybe there is a better approach.

Comment: One trivial optimization: store this expression in a variable like so: `res = 2**a*3**b*5**c*7**d`, to avoid recalculating the expression multiple times.

Comment: @JonSG Actually very faster because I'm curious about the result if I extend the range of a,b,c,d to higher numbers.

Comment: I wonder if doing some of this in `log10` space is going to be faster, e.g. use `log(2**a*3**b*5**c*7**d) = a*log(2) + b*log(3) + ...`

Comment: @Reilas Not a specific value. Actually I'm intrigued by the results and I want to extend the range of a,b,c,d to see what happens.

Comment: @User, I suggest researching _[low-level programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language)_.  This will include languages that allow for faster memory allocation, thus faster computation.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? It looks like you're trying to implement a brute-force zero-finding algorithm for the equation `2**a * 3**b * 5**c * 7**d = 0.3048`? Is there a reason you want to brute-force it? It's possible that you can significantly reduce the computational work required if you replace the brute-force approach with something smarter

Comment: @User The 4 loops in this script are highly parallelizable in this case, so just using numba's `prange` you can do this in few seconds (instead several minutes in plain python)

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks a lot for the answer and comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For these kind of computations you can try `numba` JIT:

```py
from numba import njit


@njit
def fn():
    for a in range(-100, 101):
        for b in range(-100, 101):
            for c in range(-100, 101):
                for d in range(-100, 101):
                    n = (2.0**a) * (3.0**b) * (5.0**c) * (7.0**d)
                    v = n - 0.3048
                    if abs(v) <= 1e-06:
                        print(
                            "a=",
                            a,
                            ", b=",
                            b,
                            ", c=",
                            c,
                            ", d=",
                            d,
                            ", the number=",
                            n,
                            ", error=",
                            abs(n - 3.048),
                        )


fn()
```

Running this code on my machine (AMD 5700X) takes ~57 seconds (that's with compilation step included). In comparison, without the `@njit` (just plain Python) this takes exactly 4 minutes.

```
a= -78 , b= -89 , c= -14 , d= 89 , the number= 0.3047994427888104 , error= 2.7432005572111895
a= -78 , b= -57 , c= 50 , d= 18 , the number= 0.30479915330101043 , error= 2.7432008466989894
a= -69 , b= -85 , c= 87 , d= 0 , the number= 0.3047993420932106 , error= 2.7432006579067894
a= -63 , b= 42 , c= -99 , d= 80 , the number= 0.3048005478488736 , error= 2.7431994521511265
a= -63 , b= 74 , c= -35 , d= 9 , the number= 0.3048002583600241 , error= 2.743199741639976
a= -54 , b= 14 , c= -62 , d= 62 , the number= 0.3048007366419375 , error= 2.7431992633580626
a= -54 , b= 46 , c= 2 , d= -9 , the number= 0.30480044715290866 , error= 2.7431995528470914
a= -54 , b= 78 , c= 66 , d= -80 , the number= 0.3048001576641548 , error= 2.7431998423358452
a= -45 , b= -14 , c= -25 , d= 44 , the number= 0.30480092543511833 , error= 2.7431990745648815
a= -45 , b= 18 , c= 39 , d= -27 , the number= 0.3048006359459102 , error= 2.7431993640540897
a= -36 , b= -10 , c= 76 , d= -45 , the number= 0.30480082473902875 , error= 2.7431991752609712
a= 5 , b= -44 , c= -72 , d= 82 , the number= 0.30479914163960603 , error= 2.743200858360394
a= 14 , b= -72 , c= -35 , d= 64 , the number= 0.304799330431799 , error= 2.743200669568201
a= 14 , b= -40 , c= 29 , d= -7 , the number= 0.3047990409441057 , error= 2.743200959055894
a= 23 , b= -100 , c= 2 , d= 46 , the number= 0.30479951922410875 , error= 2.7432004807758914
a= 23 , b= -68 , c= 66 , d= -25 , the number= 0.30479922973623635 , error= 2.7432007702637637
a= 29 , b= 91 , c= -56 , d= -16 , the number= 0.30480014600271205 , error= 2.743199853997288
a= 38 , b= 31 , c= -83 , d= 37 , the number= 0.30480062428444915 , error= 2.743199375715551
a= 38 , b= 63 , c= -19 , d= -34 , the number= 0.30480033479552704 , error= 2.743199665204473
a= 47 , b= 3 , c= -46 , d= 19 , the number= 0.30480081307756046 , error= 2.7431991869224395
a= 47 , b= 35 , c= 18 , d= -52 , the number= 0.30480052358845894 , error= 2.743199476411541
a= 56 , b= 7 , c= 55 , d= -70 , the number= 0.3048007123815079 , error= 2.7431992876184923
a= 65 , b= -21 , c= 92 , d= -88 , the number= 0.3048009011746738 , error= 2.7431990988253263
a= 97 , b= -27 , c= -93 , d= 57 , the number= 0.3047990292827057 , error= 2.7432009707172944

real    0m57,939s
user    0m0,009s
sys     0m0,009s
```

---

Looking at your code, you can use `parallel range` (`prange`) to speed up things even further:

```py
from numba import njit, prange


@njit(parallel=True)
def fn():
    for a in prange(-100, 101):
        i_a = 2.0**a
        for b in prange(-100, 101):
            i_b = i_a * 3.0**b
            for c in prange(-100, 101):
                i_c = i_b * 5.0**c
                for d in prange(-100, 101):
                    n = i_c * (7.0**d)
                    v = n - 0.3048
                    if abs(v) <= 1e-06:
                        print(
                            "a=",
                            a,
                            ", b=",
                            b,
                            ", c=",
                            c,
                            ", d=",
                            d,
                            ", the number=",
                            n,
                            ", error=",
                            abs(n - 3.048),
                        )


fn()
```

Takes on my 8C/16T machine just ~2.7 seconds.

@EDIT: Added storing intermediate results. Thanks @yotheguitou

Comment: You can also store intermediate result between loops

Comment: @yotheguitou Yes, this speeds up things even further: from 8 seconds -> 2.7 seconds :)

Comment: It's amazing how it execute in no time!!!

Answer (score 2):

This ran in a couple of minutes.

The main speed improvement is just precalculating all the powers.  I doubt the itertools actually gained me anything.

p.s.  You probably didn't mean to use .3048 in one location and 3.048 in the print message.  I changed both to .3048.  Perhaps you meant the other.

```
    import itertools
    aa = {i: 2 ** i for i in range(-100, 101)}
    bb = {i: 3 ** i for i in range(-100, 101)}
    cc = {i: 5 ** i for i in range(-100, 101)}
    dd = {i: 7 ** i for i in range(-100, 101)}

    for (a, avalue), (b, bvalue), (c, cvalue), (d, dvalue) in itertools.product(aa.items(), bb.items(), cc.items(), dd.items()):
        if abs(avalue * bvalue * cvalue * dvalue - .3048) <= 1e-6:
            value = avalue * bvalue * cvalue * dvalue
            print('a=',a, ', b=', b, ', c=', c,', d=', d,', the number=', value, ', error=', abs(value - .3048))
```